# "Uvesorascha kasuv lemor shema Yisrael..." before Yishtabach

Tags: prayer-book, nuschaot, shema, pesukei-dezimra

Some siddurim have the following phrase in between "ושמו אחד" and "ישתבח":

ובתורתך כתוב לאמר
שמע ישראל ה׳ אלקינו ה׳ אחד

"And in Your Torah it is written to say
Shema Yisrael Hashem Elokeinu Hashem Echad"

What is the origin of this phrase's insertion, and what is the purpose of its insertion at this point?

Comment: Just an idea, could it be from the time when saying Shma was banned, so it was stuck in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *Behr* Siddur (Siddur Avodath Yisroel by Roedelheim, 1868) says in the footnotes:

This is not found in the Siddurim of the Sefardim, nor in most handwritten Siddurim. (Rav Amrom, Rokach, Kol Bo, etc.) **and therefore it appears to have been copied here from the Malchioth of the Rosh Hashana Mussaf.**